# iTunes Store operation failed. You are not authorized to use this service for provider

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, itunes, provisioning-profile

I am using Xcode 7.2 and I am not able to submit my app due to a strange error:  "iTunes Store operation failed".  I've reset my certificates, reset my provisioning profiles, cleared out my keychain, and still no success.  I've also gone to "Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts" and deleted my account, and re-added my account.  I then went into "View Details" and clicked "Download All".  I've done research which all tell me to do the steps above, but I tried all these steps countless of times and I cannot seem to figure this out.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Are you using Adhoc  Distribution or Distribution Certificate?

Comment: Yes I am using Distribution @Uma

Comment: I was able to get the app out using application loader in Xcode -> Open Developer Tools -> Application Loader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I was able to upload my project to the app store was to use the Application Loader built into Xcode.  I believe that this is a new bug with Xcode 7.2.  Here is a detailed walkthrough of using Application Loader:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to member center -> Choose iOS Provisioning Profiles (Distribution) -> edit - > add file "keychain access CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest " from your device -->download provisioning profile certificate and add it to keychain access --> Quit Xcode and reopen hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

Did you try **unchecking** the **Include bitcode** option before sending your app to Apple? I have been getting the same error quite frequently and what I notice is that it could do something with internet connectivity. When I submit my app from office with high speed connection, there is no problem at all. But from home where I have lot lower speed, I have to uncheck Include bitcode to successfully submit my app.